# Applying Cauchy to a donut

Tags: complex-analysis

I am trying to show that $f(z):C \to C$ is holomorphic on all of C\0 making $$\int_{\partial B_r(0)}f(z) dz $$ independent of r. I should be able to use Cauchy on the donut region and somehow show that $$\int_{\partial B_r(0)}f(z) dz $$ is independent of r. I dont know how to show this.

My try: for the shaded region I think I can say

$$\int_{\gamma^1}f(w)dw-\int_{\gamma^2}f(w) dw$$
with the shaded region we have $\gamma_1\cup\gamma_2$ which means $$\int_{\gamma^1}f(w)dw=\int_{\gamma^2}f(w) dw$$

Comment: Is there something simpler that you can show ?

Comment: @jimjim at this moment I can't think of how to show this in a simpler way

Comment: I don't mean to show it in a simpler way, but a simpler question that you can show ,

Comment: @jimjim im sorry but I do not